# Retrieve internet proxy server address via PowerShell

Tags: networking, proxy, powershell

I have to retrieve the proxy server address and port via PowerShell, so I can use the `Invoke-Webrequest -uri http://some-site.com -Proxy` command. The expected output should looks like http://proxy-server.com:port.

I there a PowerShell function to retrieve the proxy server address and port, so we can use it in a script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the PowerShell function to achieve my goal :

```
function Get-InternetProxy
 { 
    <# 
            .SYNOPSIS 
                Determine the internet proxy address
            .DESCRIPTION
                This function allows you to determine the the internet proxy address used by your computer
            .EXAMPLE 
                Get-InternetProxy
            .Notes 
                Author : Antoine DELRUE 
                WebSite: http://obilan.be 
    #> 

    $proxies = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings').proxyServer

    if ($proxies)
    {
        if ($proxies -ilike "*=*")
        {
            $proxies -replace "=","://" -split(';') | Select-Object -First 1
        }

        else
        {
            "http://" + $proxies
        }
    }    
}
```

Hope this helps !